# How to render html from a text column field in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, dynamic-content, html-safe

I have an column in database as **welcome_emil** of type **TEXT**.

I have saved the following code content saved in column as :

```
Thanks for Joining in!     \r\n\r\nYou can loginor refer your friends using your %referral_link%."
```

When i try to render this code into my email that is sent to the user. Complete content goes fine but

```
  \r\n\r\n
```

this is omitted and all text appear inline.

Here is the code that i use

```
  <%= p  @company.welcome_email.gsub('%referral_link%',@recipient.referral_link).html_safe %>
```

Here is the screenshot how it looks like in email

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [GEM REDCARPET](http://rubygems.org/gems/redcarpet). Details here http://rubygems.org/gems/redcarpet.

And the following code works perfectly fine for me.

```
<% markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true) %>
<% welcome_email = @site.welcome_email.gsub('% referral_link%',@recipient. referral_link) %>
<%= markdown.render(welcome_email).html_safe %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
     <%= @site.welcome_email.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rails's method [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) which will convert line ending into `<br>` tags

Comment: <%=  simple_format(@site.welcome_email.gsub('%share_referral_link%',@recipient.short_url)) %>